# How to get reference to the iframe from which script html tag was generated?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have small snippet that is inside iframe and generates script html tag and appends it to the window.top.document.head.

Now I want to know **how do I check from within potato.js from which iframe it was generated from** once it is already loaded?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe>
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                
            </head>
            <body>
                <script>
                    (function() {
                        var s = document.createElement('script');
                        s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
                        s.setAttribute('src','https://test.com/potato.js');
                        window.top.document.head.appendChild(s);
                    })();
                </script>
            </body>
            </html>
        </iframe>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Edit: I can not change this code inside the iframe

Answer (score 1):

That information isn't stored automatically.

The only way I can think of would be to add an expando-prop to the script with a reference to the current window (i.e. the frame's window)…

```
s.sourceWindow = window;
```

… then read that from within potato.js …

```
const sourceWindow = document.currentScript.sourceWindow;
```

… and then loop over all the frames (`window.frames`) looking for a match.

Since you are using `window.top` and not `window.parent` you might need to be recursive there.

Comment: The only problem is that I can not change this code inside the iframe anymore :( 
So then the only option would be to loop throw every iframe in the website and search for "potato.js" keyword ?